# Parsing a String - Http string

Tags: java, string, parsing, html-parsing

I wanna do something like this!
So i am only left with the website part of the string. I was having problems with the quotations within the string.

```
     /////////////////////This is what i read into a string.

          ///<td width="118"><a href="research.html" class="navText style10 style12">

  ///////I wanna be able to parse this so i am only left with research.html

   //I sometimes also get a string that contains:

  //<a href="http://www.ucalgary.ca" class="style18"><font size="3">University of    Calgary</font></a></div>

     //From this string i wanna keep http://www.ucalgary.ca
```

What I got so far doesnt always work for every case. I would appreciate your help!! My code is

```
        public class Parse
        {
          public static void main(String[] args)
          {
            String h = "<a href=\"http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm\">";
            int n = getIndexOf(h, '"', 0);


            String[] a = h.substring(n).split(">");
            String url = a[0].replaceAll("\"", "");
            //String value = a[1].replaceAll("</a", "");

            System.out.println(url + "  " );
          }

          public static int getIndexOf(String str, char c, int n)
          {
            int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
            while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
            {
              pos = str.indexOf(c, pos + 1);
            }
            return pos;
          }
        }
```

Comment: look at the java String methods. They have stripping and such

Comment: It's not clear, from your input, "<a href=\"http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm\">", what do you want to keep/extract ?

Comment: only departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm /// This input works but the other inputs i mentioned above dont seem to work!! For example if i use this as input///// <a href="http://www.ucalgary.ca" class="style18"><font size="3">University of    Calgary</font></a></div>

Answer (score 0):

I would give Pattern and Matcher a try like this:

```
    String s = "<a href=\"http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm\">";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*href=\"([^\"]*).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Little code:

String h = "http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm\">";
String url = h.substring(h.indexOf("http")).replace("\">", "");
System.out.println(url);

Output will be: 
http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm

Tested on my machine.

Also post what are possible cases. So that I can tell you better solution.

Solution for all three posibilities:

```
        //String h1 = "<a href=\"http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm\">";
        //String h1 = `"<a href=\"ucalgary.ca\"; class=\"style18\"><font size=\"3\">University of Calgary</font></a>";
    String h1="<td width=\"118\"><a href=\"research.html\" class=\"navText style10 style12\">";`

String url = h1.substring(h1.indexOf("href=\"") + "href=\"".length()).substring(0, h1.substring(h1.indexOf("href=\"") + "href=\"".length()).indexOf("\""));

System.out.println(url);
```

Uncomment String h1; object one by one and check your requirements.

Above code is giving output: 
research.html 
http://www.departmentofmedicine.com/policy.htm 
ucalgary.ca

Comment: This is another case: <td width="118"><a href="research.html" class="navText style10 style12">

Comment: this is also another case: <a href="http://www.ucalgary.ca" class="style18"><font size="3">University of Calgary</font></a></div>

Comment: Vishwajit, thanks for your help, it works perfectly!!

Comment: If you have any problem you can ask me.

Comment: Hi, Vishwajit. I was having trouble with a networking assignment in Java, Im not sure if you are familiar with network programming including sockets and client and server. If you can help me out I would really appreciate it. You can reach me at my email: hasanq789@gmail.com